# Clone dynamically added html content with JQuery clone() method

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, clone, dynamically-generated

I have a table with rows containing user information.

When some user clicks the `<a id="modify1" data-userid="value">` link for that row, there is hidden `<div id="formContainer"></div>` that gets dynamicaly populated with a `<form>` tag (via JQuery `load('getuserupdateform.php?user_id=X')` method) for updating that user.

After the call to `load()` method, i call another function `showModal()` that puts `<div id="formContainer"></div>` (and it's dynamically added content) into a modal window.

But the problem is that the dynamically added `<form>` element is not present into the modal window.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    $('a.modify').click(function() {
        $('#formContainer).load('getuserupdateform.php?user_id=X');
        return showModal($(#formContainer));
    });

  showModal = function(element) {
    var modal;
    modal = element.clone();
    //Code for creating the modal window
  }
```

It appears that the `clone()` method doesn't clones the dynamically added `<form>` element.

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use `$('a#modify1')`, since `modify1` is ID and not class.

You are running showModal, without checking if `load` method completed, and so it couldnt find any `<form>` to clone.

Try putting showModal as a callback to the load function:

```
$('a#modify').click(function() {
    $('#formContainer).load('getuserupdateform.php?user_id=X', function(){
        return showModal($(#formContainer));
    });
});
```

This way, showModal will run ONLY when the `load` request has completed.

Detailed explanation on how callback works : http://api.jquery.com/load/